# QuickBooks SDK - QUICKBOOKS_ADD_RECEIVEPAYMENT

Tags: php, xml, quickbooks

Here is the XML being sent to the web connector and I am always getting the response:

```
Incoming XML response: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
 <QBXMLMsgsRs>
   <ReceivePaymentAddRs requestID="139" statusCode="3040" 
   statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="There was an error when converting 
     the amount &quot;195&quot; in the field &quot;PaymentAmount&quot;. " />
     </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Here is the XML:

```
Outgoing XML request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="6.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID="139">
                <ReceivePaymentAdd>
                    <CustomerRef>
                        <ListID>8000000C-1495707156</ListID>
                    </CustomerRef>
                    <TxnDate>2017-05-26</TxnDate>
                    <RefNumber>P123</RefNumber>

                    <Memo>Inv. #123</Memo>
                    <AppliedToTxnAdd>
                    <TxnID>78-1495715192</TxnID>
                    <PaymentAmount>195</PaymentAmount>
                </AppliedToTxnAdd>
                </ReceivePaymentAdd>
            </ReceivePaymentAddRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>
```

I have tried using the autoApply and specifying the details of where to apply the payment. Both im getting the same response.

Answer (score 0):

A valid amount value has dollars *and cents*:

- 1000.00

Also note that if your client is using non-US currency settings (e.g. they type `1000,00` with a comma instead of a decimal point) then you'll have to make sure you provide amounts in the currency format their computer is set to instead.

Comment: Then please post the actual full qbXML request (not your PHP code, but the actual request from the quickbooks_log SQL table or the Web Connector log) and the full qbXML response. Added an additional note to check up above as well.